# How to use smtp password with git-multimail

Tags: git, email, smtp, post-commit

According with this [README](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/contrib/hooks/multimail/README?id=HEAD) there is an option to send post commit notification via smtp:

> multimailhook.mailer 
>       - smtp: use Python's smtplib.  This is useful when the sendmail
>         command is not available on the system.  This mode can be
>         further customized via the following options:

But i can't realize how to use smtp password with this option.
 Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't possible until today, but I've just merged a pull-request adding support for authenticated SMTP: https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail/blob/master/git-multimail/README#L272